# I believe my question was removed, don't know why

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I believe my question was deleted, or I posted it somewhere in a completely different place and forgot it, but I'm 92.1% sure I posted it here (among other places like irc)

It was about plasmashell eating a lot of ram, which made my work almost impossible.

If it was removed, can someone tell me why?

BTW, I found the solution of the problem after many hours of searching for a reason, and it's a bug in plasma. I came back here to answer my question to help others :(

Comment: Just for the future, please don't cross post questions on SE (ie post the same question on [ubuntu.se] and [unix.se]). It's frowned upon, and seen as impatience/point-collecting/attention-grabbing/etc. If you posted on non-SE sites and only one SE site, then it's fine.

Comment: I know I shouldn't cross post, I usually don't do it, it's just that I was really tired of this bug. So, after getting no help on irc, I tried somewhere else, I just can't recall where was that :) I'm sorry for the confusion, @Zacharee1 and thanks guntbert for correcting my English :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at your activity page: https://askubuntu.com/users/511388/konrad-firm?tab=topactivity there is 1 question listed: [On KDE how to change taskbar's font size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824353/on-kde-how-to-change-taskbars-font-size)

Comment: Yes, this is why I thought someone deleted it entirely, so that even I in my own panel can't see it, but OK, it seems I need some sleep, thanks @Rinzwind